# Which class to use integrate for DirectFB with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qtembedded, directfb

I want to integrate DirectFB with Qt. Which Qt class will be useful for it in Qt 4.8?

Answer (score 1):

There is no public class as a middleware component dedicated to DirectFB. There is a plugin, however, that you can enable in the following way:

```
./configure -plugin-gfx-directfb
```

or

```
./configure -qt-gfx-directfb
```

Note that you would better use Qt Embedded for that. Please read the [following documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt-embeddedlinux-directfb.html) for details.

That being said, I suggest to wipe Qt 4 out of your mind, and concentrate on Qt 5, which is much neater in this regard. There is a proper directfb QPA plugin in there, etc.

Comment: Thank u so much. I configured and enabled my QT with these plugins. But now how to correlate. I mean which class i should invoke in my QT program to link both of them together.

Comment: As the linked documentation writes, QWidget, QImage, QPainter, etc. with certain restrictions.